# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'JToken.Parent' of type 'JContainer'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, aspnetcoretemplatepack

I am using the 'Asp.Net Core 2.0' and installed nuget package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore' version '3.0.0-preview5.19227.1', when I want to use a IQuarable functions, I get the above Error.

```
    public partial class Wfuser
    {
        public Wfuser()
        {
            UserRole = new HashSet<UserRole>();
        }

        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public virtual Userauth Userauth { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRole { get; set; }
    }

   public class NormalUser : IUser
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public NormalUser(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            this.UserName = UserName;
            this.Password = Password;
        }
        public Wfuser CurrentWFUSER { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        ITTMSContext db;
        public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
        public UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
        public bool Authenticate()
        {
            db = new ITTMSContext();
            CurrentWFUSER = db.Wfuser.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == UserName);
            int idUser = CurrentWFUSER.IdUser;
        }

    }
```

The full error message was:

'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'JToken.Parent' of type 'JContainer'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found that by myself. 
As the error message has mentioned, I should add a `[NotMapped]` attribute before the properties which is not in my table fields.